# Node.JS Readline prints a new line on backspace keypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I have some code to read in some user input, nothing fancy:

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Please enter some text:\n', function(answer){
    rl.pause();
    console.log(answer);
});
```

Unfortunately, when the user is prompted for the input, if they make a typo and attempt to use `BACKSPACE` to delete the text, the prompt is shifted down a line. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking into this further, it appears it only occurs if the `rl.question()` prompt contains a `\n`. If the prompt doesn't contain a newline character, the text can be backspaced safely.

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Please enter some text: ', function(answer){
    rl.pause();
    console.log(answer);
});
```